# Variables inside application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Is there a way to save value inside variable and reuse it inside application.properties.

If I have something like :

```
 spring.datasource.username: root
 spring.datasource.password: root
```

I would like to reuse it like :

```
org.quartz.dataSource.timermicroservice.user = ${spring.datasource.username}
org.quartz.dataSource.timermicroservice.password = ${spring.datasource.password}
```

Or something similar. Is there a way for thing like this ?

Comment: Have you tried it that way? Because this seems to me that this is the right way to do it

Comment: Yes, I have. Got -> "Could not load driverClass ${spring.datasource.driverClassName}"

Comment: Maybe you need to use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to achieve what you wanna do.
Here is an example : https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Comment: Got "Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.driverClassName' in string value "${spring.datasource.driverClassName}""

Comment: Do you have a property called `spring.datasource.driverClassName`?

Comment: @mirzak do you have only one `properties` file? And do I understand correctly that you want to have the same value (defined in `application.properties`) for two different properties?

Comment: Yes, one file. I just want to reuse my keys. I made it work different way since I could not do it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to do it like mentioned in question since Quartz uses plain Java, but in Spring it is different. So I did it like

```
spring.datasource.username = ${org.quartz.dataSource.timermicroservice.user}
spring.datasource.password = ${org.quartz.dataSource.timermicroservice.password}
```

This works.